# Voltage of an inductor

Tags: inductor

The formula for the voltage induced in an inductor is V=-L di/dt. However there is no mention of the displacement current. If the voltage is changing, there is a changing electric field and thus, a changing electric flux -> displacement current -> magnetic field -> electric field -> emf (voltage).

Comment: Are you worried about this same issue when analyzing resistors?

Answer (score 1):

[Displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) is related to capacitance (it is the 'current' that 'flows' between the the plates of a capacitor). A perfect inductor has no capacitance, so even though the voltage across it varies there is no electric field and therefore no displacement current.

Comment: But a real inductor does have capacitance.

Comment: @user1897830: So then model a real inductor.

Comment: @user1897830 I came here for assistance from the experts. Not throwaway remarks. There a dime a dozen.

Comment: A real inductor is a combination of inductance, capacitance, and resistance. If you want to account for these other components then use the appropriate formulae for them, but the formula for inductive voltage generation is still the same (and displacement current is not a factor in it).

Comment: We "experts" use models suited to the problem at hand. The ideal model of the inductor is simplest to work with, and provides adequate results in most cases. When we do care about parasitic effects, we add them as additional lumped circuit elements. If you want an exact answer for a specific inductor configuration, you'll have to use a 3-D field solver.

Comment: @Dave Tweed  That's the answer I was looking for from the experts.